# Чи абсолютно синонімічні словосполучення "гарантування безпеки" і "забезпечення безпеки"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми, словосполучення

Замість неоковирного **`забезпечити безпеку`** [професор Пономарів радить](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2014/03/140303_ponomariv_blog11) вживати ***`гарантувати безпеку`***.

> - **Читачка Оксана [не я] цікавиться, як можна замінити немилозвучний вислів `забезпечити безпеку`**.
> - Щоб уникнути тавтології, потрібно вживати *`гарантувати безпеку`*.

Водночас, аналіз [нормативно-правової бази України на сайті ВРУ](http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/main) свідчить про  те, що законодавець нехтує словосполученням **`гарантування безпеки`** (0 документів). Натомість, **`забезпечення безпеки`** - в абсолютному пріоритеті (понад 400 результатів).

**Тож чи абсолютно синонімічні згадувані словосполучення, чи є якась різниця між значеннями слів *`гарантування/гарантувати`* і *`забезпечення/забезпечити`* в обговорюваному контексті, що законодавець так наполегливо уникає першого навіть попри таку очевидну тавтологію? І, може, є якась прийнятна альтернатива?**

Answer (score 5):

Мені здається, ці вирази не є повними синонімами.

*Гарантія* зазвичай має під собою певні зобов'язання; якщо Ви *гарантуєте* безпеку, то Ви зазвичай несете відповідальність за це. В той час як *забезпечення* безпеки може мати на увазі лише дії, але необов'язково їх успіх чи відповідальність за їх успіх.

Якщо, припустімо, герцог/принц/шляхтич запрошує Вас відвідати його (потенційно небезпечні для Вас) володіння — він може особисто *гарантувати* Вам безпеку, але *забезпечувати* її, ймовірніше за все, будуть інші — його підлеглі, а не він особисто. Хоча в широкому (або приблизному) сенсі *гарантування* і *запезпечення* можуть розгортатися до одного значення — але у вужчих сенсах *гарантування* тяжіє до відповідальності, а *забезпечення* — до дій.

Якщо спробувати це довести через словники:

> **[ЗАБЕЗПЕ́ЧУВАТИ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=27522&page=922)** <…> 2. Створювати надійні умови для здійснення чого-небудь <…>.
>
> **[ГАРАНТУВА́ТИ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=17696&page=595)** <…> Давати *гарантію* у чому-небудь <…>.
> **[ГАРА́НТІЯ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=17693&page=595)** <…> *Порука* в чомусь <…>.
> **[ПОРУ́КА](http://sum.in.ua/s/Poruka)** <…> 1. *Запевнення* <…>; *прийнята на себе відповідальність* <…>.

Хоча в ширшому сенсі «він забезпечує», звісно, також може мати на увазі й лише відповідальність (чи керівництво), а не виконання дій власноруч. Це в тій чи іншій мірі властиво багатьом дієсловам (як у російського письменника Некрасова в епіграфі до «Залізниці»: «Івась: Татку, хто *будував* цю залізничну колію? Татко: Граф Петро Андрійович Клейнмихель, серденько»). Тому й означення *забезпечувати* в тому ж тлумачному словнику має продовження:

> … *гарантувати* щось.

Маючи на увазі, що і про керівника, і про безпосереднього виконавця зазвичай можна сказати, що він в тій чи іншій мірі *забезпечує*. А от *гарантує* часто лише керівник (виконавець низького рівня може виконувати свої вузькі обов'язки, але не відповідати відразу за все; і зазвичай він відповідає лише перед своїм керівництвом, а не безпосередньо перед клієнтом). Мабуть, в сучасному світі *забезпечує* вся організація, а *гарантує* керівник чи відповідальна особа (хоча в переносному сенсі «гарантує» можна сказати і в значенні «безсумнівно забезпечує», причому навіть про неістоту, наприклад, «цей мур гарантує звукоізоляцію»).

Comment: Ваша аргументація здається мені логічною. Та чи не означає в такому випадку (другий абзац відповіді), що покладення на суб'єкта дії зобов'язання *забезпечити безпеку* (чи то нормативним документом, що, як я зазначила в запитанні, більш розповсюджене, аніж *гарантувати безпеку*, чи то на підставі договірних відносин), не призводить до відповідальності за невиконання такого зобов'язання?

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, чи призводить покладання на когось зобов'язання забезпечити безпеку до його відповідальності за не(повне )забезпечення безпеки? Насправді, необов'язково; точніше, формально — обов'язково, але відповідальність може бути різною (кожен нормативно-правовий акт визначає покарання за невиконання, але воно може бути мізерним; якщо штраф за незабезпечення безпеки становить 15 грн, то це якось не тягне на гарантування безпеки, хоча забов'язання формально наклали). По-друге, я би в будь-якому разі називав це «наклали забов'язання забезпечити…», а не «… гарантувати …» — бо «наклали

Comment: зобов'язання гарантувати …» — це як «наклали зобов'язання обіцяти …» (замість «наклали зобов'язання робити …»; «я гарантую» — це фактично «я обіцяю»). В певних випадках, це, може, має сенс (замість прямо зобов'язати щось зробити —  зобов'язати укласти контракт чи ще якимось чином зобов'язати взяти наступне зобов'язання; типу, як замість конкретного бажання наказати Джинну виконати ще одне бажання) — але на практиці частіше наказують прямо щось робити, а не наказують брати ще одне зобов'язання.

Comment: Я говорю не про де-факто, а про де-юре. Як зазначено вище, в нормативних документах майже не зустрічається *гарантувати безпеку*, на відміну від *забезпечити безпеку*, а це все ж означає, що є й відповідальність за невиконання (принаймні, де-юре). Те ж саме стосується договірних стосунків. Є зобов'язання, має бути відповідальність за його невиконання. Не в тому річ. А в тому, що якщо ми стверджуємо, що сам вираз *забезпечити безпеку* з лінгвістичного погляду не такий зобов'язальний з точки зору відповідальності, то очевидна невідповідність між семантикою і юридичним застосуванням.

Comment: «Я гарантую» — це «я беру зобов'язання». «Наклали на Петра зобов'язання *гарантувати щось*» — це «наклали на Петра зобов'язання *взяти на себе зобов'язання про щось*». Простіше вже накласти на Петра зобов'язання зробити щось (забезпечити безпеку абощо), а не накладати на нього зобов'язання взяти інше зобов'язання (хоча таке теж іноді трапляється).

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, тобто якби закон казав «Петро має гарантувати …» — це була би, на мою думку, тавтологія вже чисто логічна, а не орфоепічна. Це б означало «Петро має взяти на себе зобов'язання …». Зазвичай так не роблять, зазвичай наказують прямо *щось робити* (і це автоматично означає накладання зобов'язання це робити), а не наказують *взяти зобов'язання щось робити*.

Comment: Тоді проблема в логіці з точки зору відповідальності. Бо, зважаючи на другий абзац відповіді, відповідальність там, де гарантія. Або я щось не до кінця зрозуміла.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, мабуть, я занадто складно це закрутив. І ще один аспект в голову прийшов («наказати гарантувати» закон може високопосадовцю чи іншій поважній особі, президенту наприклад; це якось вносить конотацію меншої інструктивності, більшої свободи волі, мовляв, він сам зрозуміє як найкраще). Спробую це потім переформулювати.

Comment: Гаразд, чекатиму. Дякую!

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, спробую шматочок зараз. «Відповідальність там, де гарантія» — не зовсім, «пряма констатація відповідальності там, де гарантія». Але пряма констатація відповідальності не є необхідною і є навіть зайвою для накладання відповідальності. Ось дивіться: я можу написати в законі «Оксана має сплатити податок, інакше їй покарання» (це автоматично накладе на Вас відповідальність) — а можу написати в законі «Оксана має *взяти на себе відповідальність* сплатити податок» (навіщо так складно?). 1-е — це аналог «має забезпечити», 2-е — це аналог «має гарантувати».

Comment: Якщо в законі написано «Петро має забезпечувати» — то з цього автоматично випливає, що Петро гарантує. Але в законі здебільшого немає сенсу писали «Петро має гарантувати» (бо це вже буде… другий рівень вкладеності?.. не знаю, чи зрозуміло так).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63220/discussion-between-oksana-gubrenko-and-sasha).

Answer (score 3):

*Всі відомі мені*

Повчальні джерела згодні з радою пана

1. [Onlinecorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83/)
2. [Мова — ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/inshe/garantuvati-bezpeku)
3. [Уроки української мови](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/28.htm) [(Борис Рогоза)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) в газеті [„Хрещатик“](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%97%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B0-%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3#.D0.A5.D1.80.D0.B5.D1.89.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BA),
4. Довідник [„Неправильно — правильно“](http://nepravylno-pravylno.wikidot.com/dieslova)

Натомість

1. [Російсько-український словник сталих словосполучень](http://ros-ukr-idioms.wikidot.com/o) [(Сергій Головащук)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%89%D1%83%D0%BA_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

Словники

1. СУМ надає деяку синомічність між [забезпечувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/zabezpechuvaty) й [гарантувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/gharantuvaty)
2. [УЛІФ НАН України](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) — не дуже, лише до слова „гарантувати“ є пояснення „зобовʼязуватися *забезпечити* виконання чого-небудь“
3. [Словарь української мови](http://services.ulif.org.ua/grinch) [(Борис Грінченко)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) взагалі не включає „гарантувати“
4. [Практичний словник синонинім української мови](http://zosh6.at.ua/praktichnij_slovnik_sinonimiv_ukrajinskoji_movi.pdf) [(Святослав Караванський)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2_%D0%99%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) — відносно синонімічні

[Корпора Leipzig](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?word=%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83&corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014) надає більше джерел й кількість, слово ліворуч від „безпеку“

- 36,735 = забезпечити (13,036), забезпечують (9,557), забезпечує (6,107), забезпечувати (4,651), забезпечували (1,231),  забезпечить (920), забезпечать (642), забезпечуючи (591)
- 19,994 = гарантувати (11,797), гарантує (4,168), гарантують (2,805), гарантували (620) гарантуватиме (604)

---

Як видно, слово „гарантувати“ хоч і значно менше, але є вживаним. Щодо побутового аспекту — вони є доволі синомічними. Щодо юридично — мені не відомо, хоча відміності можливі. Але є і ймовірність, що на законодавчому рівні просто існує шаблон, який існував ще за часи СРСР.